# Removing gray background on icons in Office365 app launcher

Tags: azure, icons, office365, office365-apps

I'm having an issue where the icons of my Office 365 apps in the applauncher are shown with a gray background.

Like this similar image right here (The Timewax logo here being the offending tile):

[image]

It is my wish to either change the color of the background, or if possible make the image appear in full size on the app tile. Is this possible?

My application is added as an Azure-AD application with its logo updated through the azure management portal. The logo meets the size requirements given (215 x 215 pixels)

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this?